# How to request private group using android fb sdk

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I would like to know if it is possible to make an activity using Facebook SDK on Android and request automatically a secret or private Facebook group invitation.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Apps can only invite people to a group created by that app.

Check the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/group/members